# Trying to $pull from the variable key in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
UserEventsDetails.findOneAndUpdate({"username": username},
  {$pull: { req.query.eventtype : {  "name": req.query.eventname } }
  },
  {safe: true, upsert: true, new: true},
  function(err, model){
   if (err){
     console.log("ERROR: ", err);
     res.send(500, err);
   }else{
     res.status(200).send(model);
   }
  }
);
```

I am using this to pull from the mongodb. But can't use req.query.evenrname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the update document first using the square [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) or if using ECMAScript 6 computed values with object literals to initialize properties from variables:

```
var update = {};
update[req.query.eventtype] = { "name": req.query.eventname };

// or with ES6
let update = {
    [req.query.eventtype]: { "name": req.query.eventname }
}
```

Then use the above object in your update statement:

```
UserEventsDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "username": username },
    { "$pull": update },
    { "upsert": true, "new": true},
    function(err, model){
        if (err){
            console.log("ERROR: ", err);
            res.send(500, err);
        }else{
            res.status(200).send(model);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..  Do I need to the same for $set

Comment: If the variable key field is an array then you would need the help of the `$set` operator together the postional `$` operator to correctly identify the position of the element to be updated in the array.

Comment: Can you please put an example here or point me anywhere on the internet